# using predict with averages of coefficients

Tags: r, regression, lm, predict

I have a time-series dataset and am taking a rolling average of the past 2 years of coefficients and applying that to the current year variables. I created a method that applies the average, but I am wondering if I can do this with a function like predict so I don't have to individually write out each variable.

A simplified version of my code is like this:

```
formula <- as.formula( a ~ b + c)
subset <- which(data$year == 2009)
fm1 <- lm(formula, data[subset,])

subset2 <- which(data$year == 2010)
fm2 <- lm(formula, data[subset,])

#Take average of coefficients from these two regression
avg_coeff <-  (fm1$coeff + fm2$coeff)/2   

#Apply average coefficients to current year data
subset3 <- which(data$year == 2011)
subset_data <- data[subset,]

a_hat <- avg_coeff[1] + avg_coeff[2] * subset_data$b + avg_coeff[3] * subset_data$c
```

This method works, but I want to keep the `lm` object so I can just use the predict method and do:

```
a_hat <- predict(fm, subset_data)
```

where `fm$coefficient` contains `avg_coeff`. I tried

```
fm2$coeff <- avg_coeff
```

but this does change `fm2$coeff`, but when I run the predict with `fm2`, it uses the original coefficient.

Comment: It should be `fm2$coefficients`, not `fm2$coeff`.

Comment: Oh, that seems to solve it. Do you know why when I run fm$coeff, it still spits out the coefficient?

Comment: You added a new component `coeff`to the list `fm`. But `predict` is using `object$coefficients`.

Comment: There is partial matching with the `$` function but not with the `$<-` function. Read the `?Extract` help page more carefully. It generally takes at least 10 readings and several months to get 90% of the content.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for each year maybe you can do something like

```
require(plyr)
formula <- as.formula( a ~ b + c)
fn <- function(X){  
    fm <- lm(formula, X)
    out <- fm$coefficients   
}
coeffs <- dlply(dta, .(year), fn)
avg_coeffs <- sapply(coeffs, mean)
```